# How to change HTML code inside of a div with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am building a HTML site & that site has too many pages. So I want a code so that I can edit a particular div from my website so it will apply to all over in my website.
For eg.
**In HTML >>**

```
<div id="special-id"> I want to change or place anything [HTML code also] inside of this div with javascript </div>`*
```

**& in javascript >>**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
????
</script>
```

Please need help so that I can move to my HTML website again.

I want to change a content that may be simple text or a javascript code or HTML code?

Comment: Keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a place to ask questions if you didn't try anything. You'll get downvoted to oblivion for not providing anything that you tried. This answer can be answered by searching the most basic tutorial about javascript/html.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('special-id').innerHTML = "Whatever you want to replace with";
```

Comment: It's best to include explanation with answers, not just code.

Comment: Working but can I add code given by ad networks, because they are mostally in javascript. So document.getElementById('special-id').innerHTML = "How to add ad code"; same as HTML?

Comment: Yes, you can add HTML codes too, if thats what you are asking.

Comment: Yes but ad networks give their codes with script tag so that would also work or not ?

Comment: well, I suppose it could. It depends on the exact case. Just try it and see if it works for you.

Comment: "; }//]]> this error comes Please help

Comment: You might want to escape characters like " or ' inside your code. You do that by writing \ infront of the character.

Comment: Sorry but can't understand you! Please just tell me it's solution.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way:
first, *get* your element with e.g. [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById), then set *innerHTML* to your new code.

```
var div = document.getElementById('special-id');
div.innerHTML = '<span>hello world</span>';
```

The DOM method only way:
create your new HTML nodes using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) or `document.createTextNode` and then append them to your element with [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).

```
// assuming `div` as above
var newNode = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode('hello world')
);
div.appendChild(span);
```

Comment: I think .innerHTML is the best method!

Comment: It's easy, true, but it means if you'd like to do more complicated things, such as attaching event listeners, you have to get the nodes and attach the listeners after string has been parsed they've been added to the DOM tree, and not before. It also means you can't do weird things like image caching or sending virtual events to nodes not in the tree.